# Different File Versions in Visual Studio and windows Properties

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Anyone knows why am I having different file versions of a executable file in windows properties and visual Studio?

[image: Windows File Version]

[image: Visual Studio File Version]

I'm querying the same file... for sure! What am I mising....

This is my code:

```
private string getFileVersion(string filePath)
    {
        try
        {                
            return FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(filePath).FileVersion;
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException ex)
        {
            mLogFile.addLogEntry("XML file. " + ex.Message);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

UPDATE:The File I'm querying it is not the project executable file.

thanks

Comment: They should be the same, must be a *user mistake*. Can you show your `AssemblyInfo.cs` (remove comments)?

Comment: @Sinatr The File I'm querying is not the exe from the project. It is another file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The developer of that application didn't update the "FileVersion" string to match the information in the other properties.

[image]

Build the file version information from the following information:

```
FileVersionInfo info  = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(filePath);
String version = String.Format("{0}.{1}.{2}.{3}", info.FileMajorPart
                                                , info.FileMinorPart
                                                , info.FileBuildPart
                                                , info.FilePrivatePart);
```

Comment: @Nuno, was about to post comment (after looking at [sources](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/services/monitoring/system/diagnosticts/FileVersionInfo.cs,7b4bdfe89edcc59d,references)), what there are 2 values: string version and some fixed file info. Maybe option dialog combines `GetFixedFileInfo` numbers to show version, while *string version* is unused by that dialog. To get *file version* like that dialog does you have to combine that fixed file info yourself (as in the answer code).